# Proper folder structure for go packages used by a single go project

Tags: go, structure, organization

I am currently starting with Go and have already dug into the dos and don'ts regarding package naming and workspace folder structure.

Nevertheless, I am not quite sure how to properly organize my code according to the Go paradigm.

Here is my current structure example as it resides in `$GOPATH/src`:

```
github.com/myusername/project
|-- main.go
+-- internal
+---- config
|------ config.go
```

So i have the project called `project` which uses the `config` package which, in turn, is specialized in a way that it should only be used by `project`. Hence, I do not want it under `github.com/myusername/config`, right?

The question now is, is it "good" to use the internal package structure or should I instead put my project specific packages under `github.com/myusername/$pkgname` and indicate somehow that it belongs to `project` (e.g. name it `projectconfig`)?

Comment: What is defined in `config.go`? Does it really warrant its own package? Could you not just have unexported  config types/functions/variables in your `github.com/myusername/project` package?

Comment: Isn't that possible with all functionality provided by packages? But yes, in this example i could just put the two functions and the config type into the `project` package. I'm actually more interested in the general idea of when to use internal packages, or if I should do so at all. Furthermore, is there any disavantage in creating tiny packages?

Comment: Barely any Go project has an `internal` package. If you aren't sure put `config` in your root and document your project well so users know they should not or must not use it. I personally think it's better not to think what to put where, but just write everything in one place and extract to a package/module whenever it makes sense.

Comment: So i should probably rephrase my question: Should I only use packages if the code is reusable project independent and just put everything into the `main` package otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

If your project produces one single program then the most common structure is the one you mentioned.

If your project produces more than one program the common practice is using a structure like this:

```
<project>/
  cmd/
    prog1/
      main.go
    prog2/
      main.go
```

If your project exposes go code as library for third party consumption the most common structure is using the project's root dir to expose the domain model and API.

```
<project>/
  model.go
  api.go
```

This is for third party code to just import "github.com/user/project"  and have the model and api available.

Is common to see second and third options combined.

Also is considered good practice to have packages for encapsulating dependencies usage. E.g. suppose your project uses the elastic search client

```
<project>/
  cmd/
    prog1/
      main.go
  elastic/
    impl.go
  dao.go
  model.go
```

So in dao.go you define the dao's API and then in elastic/impl.go you (import elastic library, domain modal and) define the implementation of DAO in terms of elastic. Finally you import everything from main.go which produces the actual program.

See [this](https://codeandtalk.com/v/gophercon-denver-2016/gophercon-2016-lightning-talk-ben-johnson) great and short presentation about this issue.